# Column 'type' is ambiguous in field list MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a rather complex DB that I'm working on as a school project and we are currently developing a application that is supposed to render answers in different charts depending on what type of question it was. Now I'm using this following code, but this gives me everything from three tables, and the problem is that two of the tables both have a column called "type". It is not the same "type", and I want to acces only the "type" from "module_question", since that's the one telling me what type of question it was (eg. choice-based question, free text answer etc.)

```
SELECT * FROM module_question AS mq
INNER JOIN course_module AS cm ON mq.course_module_id = cm.course_module_id 
INNER JOIN course_event AS ce ON cm.course_id = ce.course_id 
WHERE ce.course_event_id = 223 
and help_text IS NOT NULL 
AND help_text <> '';
```

But if I try this instead:

```
SELECT *, type AS question_type FROM module_question AS mq
    INNER JOIN course_module AS cm ON mq.course_module_id = cm.course_module_id 
    INNER JOIN course_event AS ce ON cm.course_id = ce.course_id 
    WHERE ce.course_event_id = 223 
    and help_text IS NOT NULL 
    AND help_text <> '';
```

It gives me

> Column 'type' is ambiguous in field list

as an error. Both "course_module" and "module_question" have a column called "type".

What's the "correct" way to do this query? I want to be able to access "type" from module_question inside my JSapplication.

Comment: You have same column names in more than one table being joined. So  don't use * and use alias with type column

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need:

```
SELECT *, mq.type AS question_type FROM module_question AS mq
INNER JOIN course_module AS cm ON mq.course_module_id = cm.course_module_id 
INNER JOIN course_event AS ce ON cm.course_id = ce.course_id 
WHERE ce.course_event_id = 223 
and help_text IS NOT NULL 
AND help_text <> '';
```

OR

```
SELECT *, cm.type AS question_type FROM module_question AS mq
INNER JOIN course_module AS cm ON mq.course_module_id = cm.course_module_id 
INNER JOIN course_event AS ce ON cm.course_id = ce.course_id 
WHERE ce.course_event_id = 223 
and help_text IS NOT NULL 
AND help_text <> '';
```

OR

```
SELECT *, ce.type AS question_type FROM module_question AS mq
INNER JOIN course_module AS cm ON mq.course_module_id = cm.course_module_id 
INNER JOIN course_event AS ce ON cm.course_id = ce.course_id 
WHERE ce.course_event_id = 223 
and help_text IS NOT NULL 
AND help_text <> '';
```

depending on what you need...

**But this way you'll get column type two times!**

Comment: So strange, I thought I tried that but now when I did it again it worked. No Idea what I did wrong :O Thank you so much!

Comment: Btw, what do you mean with "column type two times"? Will it affect me badly? It seems to work now when I'm looping thorugh the answers, the correct type is looping aswell.

Comment: @LinusSvahn You'll get all fields from all tables joined and also another field 'type' (from table you choosed) renamed as 'question_type'. So your query will show two times the same field with two different names ('type' and 'question_type')

Answer (score 0):

You must define which type from which table you want to have. For example:

```
SELECT *, mq.type AS question_type FROM module_question AS mq ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Only change mq.type instead of type.
`SELECT *, mq.type AS question_type FROM module_question AS mq`
`INNER JOIN course_module AS cm ON mq.course_module_id = cm.course_module_id`
`INNER JOIN course_event AS ce ON cm.course_id = ce.course_id`
`WHERE ce.course_event_id = 223`
`and help_text IS NOT NULL`
`AND help_text <> '';`